# What is the current of a single charged particle moving at a constant velocity?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current

Disregarding quantum and relativistic effects what is the current of a single electrically charged particle with charge $q$ moving at a constant velocity, $\vec{v}$?

I am looking into to this to make more sense of the magnetic attraction between two particles which is somewhat like:

$ \vec{F_B} = \frac{2k \left( q \vec{v} \right) \times \left(Q \left( \vec{V} \times \hat{r} \right) \right)}{c^2 |r|^2} $

Comment: Magnetism is a relativistic effect.

Comment: This is treated quite nicely in Griffiths E+M. I don't have it with me but it is nearish the end, before he starts talking about the radiation reaction.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure you are familiar with current defined on a line or on a plane or in a volume. Similarly, a point current would involve a dirac delta function. The current is

$$I = q\mathbf{v}\delta (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x'}) $$

$\mathbf{x'}$ is the position of the particle and $\mathbf{x}$ is an arbitrary point in 3 dimensional space . $\mathbf{x'}$ is a function of time. THis is kind of a trivial point in electromagnetism. You will find this in texts such as Griffiths or Jackson.

Comment: So, if I have say 10000 similar charged particles travelling around in a closely packed circle what is the current? I would have to approximate the situation using the average current at points on the circle right?